# Reactivar envelope en Docusign Node JS

Tags: nodejs, api

Hay alguna forma de "reactivar" un envelope usando la API/SDK (Node js) de docusign una vez que alguno de los firmantes declino el envelope? Y si es así se enviaría otro correo a los firmantes?